# GLFW getkey 'esc' and close window

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw

I'm trying to get a key input of 'esc' and close the window. I found two ways to do this the first one is:

```
static void key_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods){
    if (key == GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE && action == GLFW_PRESS)
        glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, GL_TRUE);
}

glfwSetKeyCallback(window, key_callback);

while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)){
    render();
}
```

the other one is:

```
    glfwSetInputMode(window, GLFW_STICKY_KEYS, GL_TRUE);

    while( glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE ) != GLFW_PRESS &&
              glfwWindowShouldClose(window) == 0 ){
    render();
}
```

I want to know if these two ways works the same? If there is any circumstance these two works differently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can say that they work kinda the same, but trust the [`glfwSetKeyCallback`](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/group__input.html#ga7e496507126f35ea72f01b2e6ef6d155) callback.

When you call [`glfwPollEvents`](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/group__window.html#ga37bd57223967b4211d60ca1a0bf3c832) then it takes all pending events and calls each respective callback accordingly. The problem is that [`glfwGetKey`](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/group__input.html#gadd341da06bc8d418b4dc3a3518af9ad2) only returns the last state for the specified key.

This becomes a problem if you (chronologically) have a *flow of events* like this:

```
*Press Escape*
*Release Escape*
glfwPollEvents() <- Calls the callback two times
glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE) <- returns GLFW_RELEASE
```

The key callback will bet called for both the press and release. However [`glfwGetKey`](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/group__input.html#gadd341da06bc8d418b4dc3a3518af9ad2) will return `GLFW_RELEASE` since that's the last state for the escape key.

So are they gonna act the same? Possibly. Can you rely on that always being the case? No.